# Include multiline python code into a Makefile

Tags: python, bash, shell, makefile

When I'm working on a bash script and need to write a particularly complex logic I usually fall back on using python, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

function foo() {
    python << END
if 1:
    print "hello"
END
}

foo
```

How can I do the same thing from within a Makefile?

Comment: Just write an actual external script?

Comment: Or switch to `scons`, where Python code isn't just allowed, it's required.

Comment: That is not what Makefiles are for, to include complex procedural logic.  Make is not a procedural but declarative language.  Like Etan says, write a separate script.

Answer (score 0):

You may write a bash script containing your functions, say `myscript.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

foo() {
    python << END
if 1:
    print "hello $1"
END
}
```

Now here is a `Makefile`:

```
SHELL = /bin/bash

mytarget ::
    @source myscript.sh ;\
    foo world
```

Finally type in your terminal:

```
$ make mytarget
hello world
```

Some explanations on the `Makefile`: defining `SHELL` let `make` know which shell to run. The `::` stands for phony target (and a little more); you can replace it with `:` for an actual target.

The key point is to run `source` and call the function in the same shell, that is, in the same line (since `make` run a different shell for each line); this is achieved by `;\` at the end of each line.